# Amstrad CPC 6128 - Bench Power Supply Connection Setup

Tags: power, cpc, amstrad

I am definitely at the very beginning of my refurb-journey and learning every step now on the way ... I struggle with the following: I saw a video by Noel's Retrolab where he troubleshooted a CPC.

He connected his bench power supply to the CPC, but I just cannot figure out the cabling setup. How do you properly set this up? Are there adaptor cables from banana plug to the power jack? It seems he uses the female connector that leads to the display output?

[image: Noel's Retro Lab]

Comment: Good question. If you are fixing up an Amstrad CPC, you are asking in the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CPC Machines were powered by 5v DC from monitor to the 2.1mm socket on the machine. Any power supply that meets these requirements with the correct polarity should work. The plug has one outer and one inner contact. The outer contact is 0V, and the inner contact is 5V.

However, disc models also needed a separate 12v for the drive. This is the curly wire ending in a plug that you can see leaving the board in the photo helpfully added to your question.